# Por qué los tiempos verbales no coinciden para “iba a llegar” y “tiene que”?

Tags: tiempos-verbales

> Tom me ha enviado un mensaje de texto para decirme que **iba a llegar** un
>    poco tarde porque **tiene que ir** a tomar algo con un cliente.

Pregunta:
Por qué los tiempos no coinciden para “iba a llegar” y “tiene que”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso la coincidencia no se da porque lo que se quiere expresar ocurre en tiempos diferentes.

Lo primero va en pasado.

> Tom me ha enviado un mensaje

Como el mensaje hablaba del futuro (en el momento del mensaje) pero eso debió haber pasado ya, entonces esa parte también puede decirse en pasado.

> ... iba a llegar ...

y como en el momento del mensaje y tal vez en el momento actual Tom tiene que atender un cliente, entonces esa parte va en presente.

> ... tiene que ir ...

En estos casos puede haber incluso otras combinaciones de tiempos dependiendo de cuando pasaron o pasarán las cosas. Por ejemplo también es válido decir:

> Tom me **envió** un mensaje de texto para decirme que **va** a llegar un poco tarde porque **tenía** que ir a tomar algo con un cliente.

Aquí cambia "iba a llegar" (pasado) por el futuro "va a llegar" en caso de que Tom todavía no haya llegado pero piensa llegar. También se cambia "tiene que ir" (presente) por el pasado "tenía que ir" porque tal vez Tom ya atendió a su cliente lo que le ocasionó un retraso pero de igual forma *va a llegar* aunque sea tarde.

Obviamente también es correcto si toda la oración está en pasado porque todos los eventos ya ocurrieron.

> Tom me **ha enviado** un mensaje de texto para decirme que **iba a llegar** un poco tarde porque **tenía** que ir a tomar algo con un cliente.

- ha enviado (envió el mensaje en el pasado)
- iba a llegar (llegó tarde o incluso nunca llegó)
- tenía (ya atendió a su cliente)

Comment: El tema puede llegar a ser mucho más complicado; por ejemplo, yo usaría *Tom me **envió** un mensaje*. La elección de tiempos puede causar infinitos enredos con respecto al uso del pretérito y del antepresente, pues entrega una miríada de interpretaciones a la hora de analizar las otras partes del discurso que, en este caso, acá se mencionan.

Comment: @Ustanak estoy de acuerdo, por eso usé **envió** en el segundo ejemplo. Creo que esa forma nos suena más natural a este lado del Atlántico (tal vez es sólo mi impresión)

Answer (score 2):

También puedes decir

> Tom me ha enviado un mensaje de texto para decirme que **va a llegar** un poco tarde porque **tiene que ir** a tomar algo con un cliente.

si tu cita con Tom es (todavía) en el futuro o para indicar la seguridad de que Tom con seguridad va a llegar tarde. De la misma forma "**tiene que ir** a tomar algo con un cliente" implica que esa acción está en el futuro de Tom (y el nuestro).

> Tom me ha enviado un mensaje de texto para decirme que **iba a llegar** un poco tarde porque **tenía que ir** a tomar algo con un cliente.

Esta última puede implicar que Tom tenía en un principio que hacer la tarea y ya no tiene que hacerla o que Tom ya la ha completado (o está en ello).

El uso de tiempos de la frase parece efectivamente un poco arbitrario. A mi me da a entender que

1. El aviso de Tom de que seguramente llegaría tarde se produjo en nuestro pasado (por eso decimos que Tom dijo que  "iba a llegar tarde" y no "va a llegar" o "llegará" tarde, aunque estas opciones son igualmente válidas y correctas).
2. La acción de quedar con el cliente está todavía en el futuro de Tom y el nuestro (y "tendrá que" podría ser otra opción válida).